# Python sort list by algorithm

Tags: python, sorting

I have the following list

```
[
    '<td>1</td>', '<td>2</td>', '<td>3</td>', '<td>4</td>',
    '<td>A</td>', '<td>B</td>', '<td>C</td>', '<td>D</td>',
    '<td>I</td>', '<td>II</td>', '<td>III</td>', '<td>IV</td>',
]
```

What is the algorithm to sort this to match:

```
[
    '<td>1</td>', '<td>A</td>', '<td>I</td>,
    '<td>2</td>', '<td>B</td>', '<td>II</td>,
    '<td>3</td>', '<td>C</td>', '<td>III</td>,
    '<td>4</td>', '<td>D</td>', '<td>IV</td>,
]
```

I'm not sure how to describe the change in programming slang, other than that the indented order should now follow vertically instead of horizontally.. I only know the sequence length of the original list (in this case 4)

This is not homework, I am just cracking my brains figuring this out on shell any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write a custom sort function

Comment: And your problem appears more like a grouping problem than a sorting problem

Comment: Divide the elements in different kinds, sort them(in your example is not needed) and then `zip` them together.

Comment: You have *one* list, and there are no columns *yet*. Group the values into columns (nested lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Data = [
    '<td>1</td>', '<td>2</td>', '<td>3</td>', '<td>4</td>',
    '<td>A</td>', '<td>B</td>', '<td>C</td>', '<td>D</td>',
    '<td>I</td>', '<td>II</td>', '<td>III</td>', '<td>IV</td>',
]

lists, result = [], []
for i in range(0, len(Data), 4):
    lists.append(Data[i:i+4])

for currentList in zip(*lists):
    result += list(currentList)
print result
```

**Output**

```
['<td>1</td>', '<td>A</td>', '<td>I</td>',
 '<td>2</td>', '<td>B</td>', '<td>II</td>',
 '<td>3</td>', '<td>C</td>', '<td>III</td>',
 '<td>4</td>', '<td>D</td>', '<td>IV</td>']
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a sort, it's a *transposition*.

Your array elements are numbered [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..] and you want to move them to [0, 4, 8, 1, 5, 9, 2, ..], i.e.

```
newpos(x) = oldpos(x)/4 + 4*(oldpos(x) % 4)
```

where the first half is the new *column* number and the second half is the new *row* number.